# Git / Gitosis - Repository Read Access Denied

Tags: git, version-control, gitosis

I have installed git on a ubuntu Server. From my local machine using tortoiseGIT I have cloned the gitosis-admin to my local machine. Everything worked fine. 
After checking out the gitosis-admin repository to manage my keys and my Repositories in gitosis.conf, i added the new repository gittest to the .conf file.
Now the fallowing steps failed:

- create a new folder on my local manchine named gittest
- added a testfile
- committed
- push the local repository to the server the client says:

"ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied"

This error also appears if I init the repository on the server using "git init" in a new created folder at /srv/git/repositories/gittest, add a file so that the repository to clone isn't empty, an try to clone it to my local machine.

Can anybody help to solve this error?

Comment: Did you commit and push your gitosis-admin first?

Comment: How does your gitosis config file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `git init --bare` in /srv/git/repositories/gittest instead of `git init`.

Comment: You don't have to git-init the remote repository when using gitosis. It's created automatically when pushing to it.